# ionic 6 capacitor angular file download from server using PHP

Tags: download, capacitor, ionic6

I am beginner to ionic. I tired many code to download image file from php server using ionic 6 capacitor angular. But nothing is working. Please help me to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: check this link https://programmierfrage.com/items/ionic-capacitor-file-download-with-php

Comment: I tried like this, but it is not working. And also no solution given in that page.